# Where can I find a "Melty Cheese Wheel"?

Tags: food-and-drink, paris, switzerland, amsterdam

I'm going to Switzerland (Geneva), also to Paris, and Amsterdam, there's some place where can I find a "Melty Cheese Wheel"?

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52d6UhLdiSw

Looks like that the real name for this dish is "Raclette"

Comment: I have voted to leave this question open as it is about a kind of food, not a specific restaurant. And in my view it is also not too broad as it is not a common food in all areas mentioned.

Comment: You want the cheese itself or a place to eat it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for *raclette*:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raclette

The dish originates from the Swiss canton of Valais, not far from Geneva, which means the dish is quite common there. For the locals it's a winter dish, but there are quite a few (somewhat touristy) restaurants that serve it all year round, like this:

http://www.aubergedesaviese.ch/

Plenty of raclette/fondue places in Paris as well, just Google for "raclette Paris".

Comment: "Savoyard" (even if its technically from Valais) is probably a good search term for Paris

Comment: I didn't knew that the name for this was "Raclette", very happy to know it know!